# why would my ping pong code implemented under mpi run into idle?

Tags: c, mpi

here is my ping pong code downloaded from [mpitutorial](https://github.com/mpitutorial/mpitutorial/blob/gh-pages/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/code/ping_pong.c)

```
// Author: Wes Kendall
// Copyright 2011 www.mpitutorial.com
// This code is provided freely with the tutorials on mpitutorial.com. Feel
// free to modify it for your own use. Any distribution of the code must
// either provide a link to www.mpitutorial.com or keep this header intact.
//
// Ping pong example with MPI_Send and MPI_Recv. Two processes ping pong a
// number back and forth, incrementing it until it reaches a given value.
//
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  const int PING_PONG_LIMIT = 10;

  // Initialize the MPI environment
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  // Find out rank, size
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // We are assuming 2 processes for this task
  if (world_size != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "World size must be two for %s\n", argv[0]);
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
  }

  int ping_pong_count = 0;
  int partner_rank = (world_rank + 1) % 2;
  while (ping_pong_count < PING_PONG_LIMIT) {
    if (world_rank == ping_pong_count % 2) {
      // Increment the ping pong count before you send it
      ping_pong_count++;
      MPI_Send(&ping_pong_count, 1, MPI_INT, partner_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      printf("%d sent and incremented ping_pong_count %d to %d\n",
             world_rank, ping_pong_count, partner_rank);
    } else {
      MPI_Recv(&ping_pong_count, 1, MPI_INT, partner_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
               MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
      printf("%d received ping_pong_count %d from %d\n",
             world_rank, ping_pong_count, partner_rank);
    }
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

here is my executing log:

```
$ mpicc ./ping_pong.c -o ping_pong
$ mpirun -np 2 ./ping_pong        
0 sent and incremented ping_pong_count 1 to 1
0 received ping_pong_count 2 from 1
0 sent and incremented ping_pong_count 3 to 1
0 received ping_pong_count 4 from 1
1 received ping_pong_count 1 from 0
1 sent and incremented ping_pong_count 2 to 0
1 received ping_pong_count 3 from 0
1 sent and incremented ping_pong_count 4 to 0
^C
```

As above, when program increase `ping_pong_count` to 4 and sent it, the program would not output anymore. But the limit set in the code is 10, I don't know why this happened.

I expected that the variable of `ping_pong_count` would finally be increased to 10.

my platform is archlinux and I am using openmpi with version 4.1.5.

Comment: The issue you are experiencing with your MPI ping pong program seems to be related to a deadlock situation.

Comment: 1. This is not a ping-pong code because the second process never sends back. 2. Output to the terminal is no guarantee of correctness. Can you remove the print statements and only print after the loop?

Comment: thanks for your comments, I have found that the problem is related to my operating system because the code is running well on wsl.

Comment: Hi all, I have found a similar issue posted on openmpi/opmi repo, and the develop had given an answer to that issue https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/11934#issuecomment-1733065215